# tap gesture not recognized on uiimageview

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, ios6.1

I added two `uiimageview`s, one on another `subview uiview` (`imageview1,imageview2`). In the first view the top `uiimageview` is hidden(`imageview2`) and in the second view the bottom `imageview` is hidden(`imageview1`).

Allocating tap gesture:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap:)];
```

Set user interaction for both uiimageview to YES.

```
[singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[singleTap1 setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
```

// adding gesture to uiimageview

Add tap gesture recognizer and selector respectively.

```
[imageview1 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[imageview2 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap1];
```

But my taps are not recognized.

Can any one tell me where the mistake is?

Comment: let me know if you solved your problem.

Comment: As per my code its wrking fine in landscape but not wrking in portrait

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Try setting `setUserInteractionEnabled:YES` before adding gesture recognizer.

```
[imageview1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]
[imageview2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]

[imageview1 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[imageview2 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap1];
```

**Update:**

After the comment you have made I suggest you bring your views to the top before detecting the tap event. Because parent imageView is above and catches these taps.

```
[yourparentview bringSubviewToFront:imageview1];
[yourparentview bringSubviewToFront:imageview2];
```

Comment: i have add 10 imageview all working fine except uiimageview in which one imageview is placed over another image view

Comment: no it is still not working .. in portrait but in landscape its working fine

Comment: Nice! Just clicked that on for the image view in Storyboard and it all works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Superb!! you are awesome man, how can i forgot **setUserInteractionEnabled**

Comment: you can also set this using interface builder in image properties

Answer (score 2):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
singleTap.delegate = self;
[imageview1 addGestureRecogniser:singleTap];
[singleTap1 release];

imageview1.userInteractionEnabled = YES; //disabled by default
```

Comment: tap gesture is working fine when two imageview placed in different location. problem is when two imageview placed in same location. hidden one in first time then hidden another in second time

Comment: So you want to toggle the visibility of imageViews on user tap, at the same location ?