# Detect Touch Event On UIScrollView's Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollview with UIImageView's inside it.

If I add gestures to the UIImageView before they are added to the scrollview, the touch event is not fired.

I want to get the UIImageView that a tap occurs at.

I have seen some answers that touch about getting the point of the touch from the UIScrollView and then calculating the UIImageView based on the position --- but that seems really messy and overkill.

Is there a simple way to get a touch event from an object inside a UIScrollView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UIImageView`s probably have user interaction disabled (which is what they default to). Call the following line on each image view, and your taps should be recognized:

```
yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Make sure to do this [*before* adding the gesture recognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218120/1145804).

I had this exact issue a few weeks ago and this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: BINGO! This is EXACTLY what I needed to get it working. Spot on thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness.

The UIImageView inside of UIScrollView is not programmed to receive touch events and gestures natively.

So what you may want to do is:

1. Add UITapGestureRecognizer to the scroll view for enabling touch inside scroll view.

>

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];

singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 

[myScrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

2. Customize the UIImageView with you view inherited from UIImageView.

>

```
CustomImageView *imageView = [[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

3. Provide touch methods in that custom subclass and add it on your UIScrollView..

>

@interface CustomImageView : UIImageView{}

@implementation CustomImageView

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {}
```

@end

Comment: Thanks! I think "singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;" is the key.