# Tap Gesture Scroll View IOS

Tags: ios, scroll, gesture, tap

I have a image view inside a scroll view and I add a tap recognise to the image view and it work but when i scroll it will transform the image view and the tap recogniser is gone .

```
         // Avatar -----------

        let avatarScaleFactor = (min(offset_HeaderStop, offset)) / userImage.bounds.height / 1.4 // Slow down the animation
        let avatarSizeVariation = ((userImage.bounds.height * (1.0 + avatarScaleFactor)) - userImage.bounds.height) / 2.0
        avatarTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(avatarTransform, 0, avatarSizeVariation, 0)
        avatarTransform = CATransform3DScale(avatarTransform, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 1.0 - avatarScaleFactor, 0)
```

Comment: After scroll bring imageview to front and check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding imagesView in scrollView using for loop i.e programmatically,then add gesture for every imageView and then test.Hope it will work.

Comment: I have a view inside got a scroll view i am adding a image view on top of the scroll view . How i am suppose to do

Comment: Are you adding only one imageView?,please elaborate hierarchy.

Comment: i found the problem but i dont know how to fixed it when the user scroll i make the image view CAtranform  using which make it smaller if i delete this line everything works fine .  Here the transform code in the question

Comment: It seems like CAtransform reset the gesture recognizer on the image view , how can i fixed this ?

Comment: First of all I can not say much without seeing code,but there is a option if gesture is reset.Use scrollView's delegate method which gets called after scrolling finished and then check for gesture on imageView if reset then add again.Make property of ImageView globally so you can access in scrollView's delegate method.

Comment: how can check the gesture on imageview?

Comment: One thing,if you are sure that gesture is reset as scroll the image on scrollView then no need to check if imageView responds to gesture or not,just addGesture to imageView

 [imageview1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]
[imageview1 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

Comment: also you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218080/tap-gesture-not-recognized-on-uiimageview ,hope it will help you.

Comment: I found the code that causing the trouble         avatarTransform = CATransform3DTranslate(avatarTransform, 0, avatarSizeVariation, 0)